# Open a pdf file using c# with textbox

Tags: c#, pdf

I want to open a specific pdf file in C#.
It's working with:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string filename = "instructions.pdf";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
}
```

and with this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Title = "Open";
        open.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf) |*.pdf;";
        open.InitialDirectory = @"C:\temp";

        try
        {
            if (open.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(open.FileName);
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

but I want open a pdf file with de name o file is in a textbox or/and in a sql table something like this:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string filename = "TEXTBOX1.pdf";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the Text property of the TextBox?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = textBox1.Text + ".pdf";
        string path = @"c:\temp\";
        string pathfilename = string.Concat(path,filename);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathfilename);
    }
```